# Perform a local operating system task in response to HTTP request received by machine

Tags: php, linux, apache, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi running Apache. I would like to start/stop a local program (like a python script), or in any other general way use the native functions on the Raspberry Pi operating system in response to HTTP requests received by the server. Is this possible using PHP?

Comment: See `exec()`, `shell_exec()` etc - as long as the user running Apache has permission to execute your native system functions, it'll be fine. If not, you could implement a "queue" type system in the middle, e.g. write to a log file for what needs to happen and have a system cron listening for changes in that file and performing them outside of the web server's scope

Comment: I'm assuming the cron will repeatedly read the file contents to figure out whether it has changed. However, I don't want more than a few seconds delay between the HTTP request and the associated action. How can this be achieved?

Comment: If you do experience permission issues when calling system commands directly from Apache you could either grant the permissions or run Apache as root, therefore no lag or queues